# Can I suggest to someone to accept my answer?

Tags: discussion, support, accepted-answer

A new user asked a [question](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/13019/how-to-teach-multiplication-between-integers-for-the-first-time) about teaching multiplication of integers for the first time.

He clearly liked my answer because (s)he wrote in a comment under my answer:

> Thank you very much! I used this method today in my classroom and it
>   was awesome. Some students even applauded lol

(S)he has not accepted my answer or any others.  I thought of suggesting to him/her that if (s)he liked my answer, (s)he could accept it, but I wasn't sure if that was an appropriate thing to do.

Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it would be better to inform the user that he or she can accept *an* answer, not necessarily *your* answer.

Although your question has been asked many times on Mathematics Meta before (see, for example, the links provided at [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4945/18398) posted on a list of comment templates), I think the following comment (by user [amWhy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276179/inequality-problem-algebra#comment610372_276179)) is a good example of how to say it politely:

> When people take time to answer your questions, and the answers are helpful to you, it is good to upvote those that are helpful. That's one way to say "thank you" so to speak. Also, for any question you ask, you can "accept" an answer. To upvote, click on the greyed-out up-arrow to the left of the answer. To accept an answer, click on the "greyed-out" check-mark next to the answer you want to accept. That indicates that the answer was particularly helpful/ and/or that it has fully answered your question.

Comment: I used your suggestion and then the user answered "Thank you! I know how the system works (I've been asking actively on mathstackexchange for years). In this question particularly, I upvoted to the answers I found helpful, but I don't want to accept any of them case because in this case I don't think there is only one answer best than another."  I am glad I didn't suggest that s/he accept my answer.  Thanks again